# Display hierarchical xml data in web page

Tags: javascript, php, python, xml, web

```
<Pathways species="homo sapiens">
<Pathway dbId="109581" displayName="Apoptosis">
 <Pathway dbId="109607" displayName="Extrinsic Pathway for Apoptosis">
  <Pathway dbId="73887" displayName="Death Receptor  Signalling">
    <Pathway dbId="75157" displayName="FasL/ CD95L signaling">
      <Reaction dbId="75244" displayName="FASL binds FAS Receptor" />
      <Reaction dbId="71050" displayName="Trimerization of the FASL:FAS receptor complex" />
      <Reaction dbId="83650" displayName="FasL:Fas binds FADD" />
      <Reaction dbId="83586" displayName="FASL:FAS Receptor Trimer:FADD complex binds pro-Caspase-8" />
      <Reaction dbId="141310" displayName="FASL:FAS Receptor Trimer:FADD complex binds pro-Caspase-10" />
    </Pathway>
  </Pathway>
</Pathway>
  </Pathway>
<Pathway dbId="109581" displayName="Signaling pathway">
</Pathway>
</Pathways>
```

Anyone who know how to display them in the website just like a tree:
something like below:

```
-Apoptosis
--Extrinsic Pathway for Apoptosis
---Death Receptor  Signalling
----FasL/ CD95L signaling
-----FASL...
-----Trimerizaiton of the FASL....
.  .
.  .
.  .
-Signaling pathway
```

I don't know how deep for the tree, but not too much.
thanks.

Comment: Thanks, totally new here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of [PHP's `SimpleXMLIterator`](http://php.net/class.simplexmliterator) which does support the standard PHP `RecursiveIterator` tree-traversal.

The following example does output this text-tree for example that comes pretty close to the kind of output you've outlined in your question:

```
|-Pathway: Apoptosis
| \-Pathway: Extrinsic Pathway for Apoptosis
|   \-Pathway: Death Receptor  Signalling
|     \-Pathway: FasL/ CD95L signaling
|       |-Reaction: FASL binds FAS Receptor
|       |-Reaction: Trimerization of the FASL:FAS receptor complex
|       |-Reaction: FasL:Fas binds FADD
|       |-Reaction: FASL:FAS Receptor Trimer:FADD complex binds pro-Caspase-8
|       \-Reaction: FASL:FAS Receptor Trimer:FADD complex binds pro-Caspase-10
\-Pathway: Signaling pathway
```

Here is an excerpt from the code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Iterator Garden Example
 *
 * Display hierarchical xml data in web page
 *
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/q/19485654/367456
 */

require __DIR__ . '/iterator_garden.php';

$file = __DIR__ . '/data.xml';
$xml  = file_get_contents($file);

$it  = new SimpleXMLIterator($xml);

$decor = new RecursiveDecoratingIterator($it, function($item) {
    return $item['displayName'] ?: $item['species'];
}, RecursiveDecoratingIterator::DECORATE_NODES);


$tree = new RecursiveTreeIterator($decor, RecursiveTreeIterator::BYPASS_CURRENT);

foreach($tree as $key => $item)
{
    echo $key, ': ', $item, "\n";
}
```

The code from [Iterator Garden is available on Github](https://github.com/hakre/Iterator-Garden), here the [`RecursiveDecoratingIterator`](https://github.com/hakre/Iterator-Garden/blob/master/src/RecursiveDecoratingIterator.php) is used.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. Do you have any idea, such as, click the top level, and then it will display all its children. Click it again, it will hide all its children.

Answer (score 0):

Look up PHP's function [xml_parse_into_struct](http://php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parse-into-struct.php), you use it to split a file like this into an array containing appropriate keys. The manual's got all the information and examples you'll need.

Alternatively, [here's an article explaining how to use SimpleXML](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-parse-xml-with-php5). Pretty easy to use too.